# Resolving Invalid Writes errors in valgrind

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, valgrind

I'm new to using valgrind and programming in C in general. I'm trying to make sense of the following valgrind message

```
==6225== Invalid write of size 4
==6225==    at 0x10000144D: handle_client (server.c:82)
==6225==    by 0x10000186A: main (server.c:201)
==6225==  Address 0x100a83248 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==6225==    at 0x10000BE81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==6225==    by 0x100001431: handle_client (server.c:80)
==6225==    by 0x10000186A: main (server.c:201)
==6225== 
==6225== Invalid write of size 4
==6225==    at 0x100001458: handle_client (server.c:83)
==6225==    by 0x10000186A: main (server.c:201)
==6225==  Address 0x100a8324c is 4 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==6225==    at 0x10000BE81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==6225==    by 0x100001431: handle_client (server.c:80)
==6225==    by 0x10000186A: main (server.c:201)
```

It resolves to this of code, in which I'm trying to allocate a struct (ClientContext)

```
#define DEFAULT_CC_CHANDLES 4
... 
[78]    // create the client context here
[79]    ClientContext* client_context = NULL;
[80]    client_context = malloc( sizeof(client_context) );
[81]    client_context->chandle_table = malloc( sizeof(GeneralizedColumnHandle) * DEFAULT_CC_CHANDLES );
[82]    client_context->chandles_in_use = 0;
[83]    client_context->chandle_slots = DEFAULT_CC_CHANDLES;
```

and the definition of that struct is:

```
typedef struct ClientContext {
    GeneralizedColumnHandle* chandle_table;
    int chandles_in_use;
    int chandle_slots;
    int client_fd;
} ClientContext;
```

So what's exactly is causing the invalid write here? Am I not allocating enough space for the struct? Should I be checking if alloc returns a valid pointer first?

Comment: Print out the result of `sizeof(client_context)`, its either 4 or 8, I bet.

Comment: Doing `sizeof` on a pointer always return the size of ***the pointer itself***, not what it points to (or what it might point to in the future, which is impossible to predict).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the size of a pointer to `malloc()` and that is not enough, try

```
client_context = malloc(sizeof *client_context);
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because `sizeof client_context` is equal to `sizeof(void *)` which is not the same as `sizeof(ClientContext)`.

Also, always check that `malloc()` actually succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

```
client_context = malloc(sizeof(*client_context));
```

The fact is that you're allocating to `client_context` the size of the pointer itself and not what it is needed inside. It's like with `char *` you do :

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * ..);
```

You put `char` inside a `char *` it's the same with the struct

Comment: But `sizeof(char)` is always *1*, it's actually specified to be *1* by the standard. So normally, no one does `sizeof(char)`, unlike `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(double)`, which can be used in common examples of how to allocate a number of elements of a given type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Fixed by changing

```
client_context = malloc( sizeof(client_context) );
```

to

```
client_context = malloc( sizeof(ClientContext) );
```

I was improperly allocating memory to the size of the variable client_context instead of the actual struct ClientContext.